# Querying a json object in typescript

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

recently i stumbled upon a problem, while getting some json data from a url.

My problem is that Datarows contains 5 rows, each row containing 47 cells.
Of the 47 cells in each row i am only interested in two of them namely:

```
  Cell with Key = "Title"
  Cell with Key = "Path"
```

So my question is: How do i query only the 2 cells i am interested in, in each row?

The interface for a cell is like this:

```
Key: string;
value: string;
ValueType: string;
```

Here is my implementation

```
let queryUrl = "/_api/search/query?querytext='" + encodeURIComponent(searchValue) + "'&rowlimit=5";
let response = await this.props.context.spHttpClient.get(queryUrl, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1.overrideWith(spSearchConfig));
let obj = await response.json();
let Datarows = obj["PrimaryQueryResult"]["RelevantResults"]["Table"]["Rows"];
```

my end result should look something like:
where cell **X** is the title cell, and cell **X+1** is the path cell

```
Row 0: Cell0, Cell1
Row 1: Cell0, Cell1
Row 2: Cell0, Cell1
Row 3: Cell0, Cell1
Row 4: Cell0, Cell1
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pretty straightforward way. I broke down the whole thing into two functions for modularity.

```
const myStrings: string[] = Datarows
    .map(getInterestingDetails) // first extract useful info
    .map(formResultString);     // then use the info

// if needed, you can also return ValueType
type InterestingDetails = {title: string, path: string};

function getInterestingDetails(row: DataRow): InterestingDetails {
    const titleCell= row.cells.find((cell: Cell) => cell.Key === 'Title');
    const pathCell= row.cells.find((cell: Cell) => cell.Key === 'Path');

    // here you could handle the case when the cell 
    // with Key = "Title" or "Path" is not found
    if (titleCell === undefined || pathCell === undefined)
        throw new Error('');

    // if needed, you can also return ValueType
    return {title: titleCell.value, path: pathCell.value};
}

// Just some string interpolation, nothing interesting here
function formResultString(details: InterestingDetails, rowIndex: number) {
    return `Row ${rowIndex}: ${details.title}, ${details.path}`;
}
```